# How to query inside jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, json

I have a column type of jsonb named **changes**

THis is the structure of my column.

```
[["change","is_enabled",[false,true]]]
```

I want to query within the column.

I want to find all the rows that "is_enabled" = true

I have tried everything. Can you please help me find a solution

Comment: Is changes = `[["change","is_enabled",[false,true]]]` or `["change","is_enabled",[false,true]]` Is it a json array, or an array of arrays?

Comment: Wat does it mean to have `is_enabled=true`?

Comment: @EvanCarroll It is [["change","is_enabled",[false,true]]] and I want to query for when [["change","is_enabled_in_client",[false,true]]] and NOT [["change","is_enabled_in_client",[false,false]]]

Comment: But you're not even using an object `{"is_enabled": true}`...

Comment: @EvanCarroll maybe I framed my question wrong. But i am not sure on how to go about this in PostgreSQL. I know how to do this in Spark SQL. I would've just used LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE. But i am lost on how to work on it in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a column type of jsonb named changes
>
> ```
> [["change","is_enabled",[false,true]]]
> ```

This is a terrible schema. You're essentially storing an array of arrays. And what you're asking is how to query a jsonb-array, for any elements that are themselves an array that happen to have an array after a string named "is_enabled" which inside the array, has an element of `true`.

```
test=# SELECT jsonb_pretty('[["change","is_enabled",[false,true]]]'::jsonb);
     jsonb_pretty      
-----------------------
 [                    +
     [                +
         "change",    +
         "is_enabled",+
         [            +
             false,   +
             true     +
         ]            +
     ]                +
 ]
(1 row)
```

That's going to be extremely ugly.  Nothing about this makes sense. Your JSON schema should just have one object that has `{"is_enabled":true}`, or something like this `{"name":"change","is_enable":true}`. As is, you need something very ugly,

You can unnest both JSON array's getting to the inside with relative ease. Then you'll have to mark the row after the `is_enabled` element in the array,

```
SELECT *,
  '"is_enabled"'::jsonb = lag(j2) OVER (PARTITION BY j1 ORDER BY o) AS is_changed
FROM ( VALUES
  ($$[["change","is_enabled",[false,true]]]$$::jsonb)
) AS t(j)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(j)
  AS jae1(j1)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(j1) WITH ORDINALITY
  AS jae2(j2,o);
                     j                     |                   j1                    |      j2       | o | is_changed 
-------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------+---+------------

 [["change", "is_enabled", [false, true]]] | ["change", "is_enabled", [false, true]] | "change"      | 1 | 
 [["change", "is_enabled", [false, true]]] | ["change", "is_enabled", [false, true]] | "is_enabled"  | 2 | f
 [["change", "is_enabled", [false, true]]] | ["change", "is_enabled", [false, true]] | [false, true] | 3 | t
(3 rows)
```

From this, it's simple using `bool_or`, and another select

```
SELECT j, bool_or(j2 @> 'true'::jsonb)
FROM (
  SELECT j, j2,
   '"is_enabled"'::jsonb = lag(j2) OVER (PARTITION BY j1 ORDER BY o) AS is_changed
  FROM ( VALUES
    ($$[["change","is_enabled",[false,true]]]$$::jsonb)
  ) AS t(j)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(j)
    AS jae1(j1)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(j1) WITH ORDINALITY
    AS jae2(j2,o)
) AS t
WHERE is_changed = true
GROUP BY j;
```

We can add more rows to the `VALUES` expression to test it

```
SELECT j, bool_or(j2 @> 'true'::jsonb)
FROM (

  SELECT j, j2,
   '"is_enabled"'::jsonb = lag(j2) OVER (PARTITION BY j1 ORDER BY o) AS is_changed
  FROM ( VALUES
    ($$[["change","is_enabled",[false,false]]]$$::jsonb),
    ($$[["change","is_enabled",[true,false]]]$$::jsonb),
    ($$[["change","is_enabled",[true,true]]]$$::jsonb)
  ) AS t(j)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(j)
    AS jae1(j1)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(j1) WITH ORDINALITY
    AS jae2(j2,o)

) AS t
WHERE is_changed = true
GROUP BY j;

                     j                      | bool_or 
--------------------------------------------+---------
 [["change", "is_enabled", [true, false]]]  | t
 [["change", "is_enabled", [true, true]]]   | t
 [["change", "is_enabled", [false, false]]] | f
(3 rows)
```

If you just want the ones where `bool_or IS TRUE` use `HAVING`..

```
WHERE is_changed = true
GROUP BY j
HAVING bool_or(j2 @> 'true'::jsonb) IS TRUE;
```